# Google Maps API Remove stored markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am saving Markers that I put in the map using an array however I would like a AlertDialog showing up asking me if I want to delete the marker in question when I tap a Marker but how would I do that? this is the code I am using for storing markers

```
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);

        // Getting number of locations already stored
        locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 0);

        // Getting stored zoom level if exists else return 0
        String zoom = sharedPreferences.getString("zoom", "0");

        // If locations are already saved
        if(locationCount!=0){

            String lat = "";
            String lng = "";
            String title = "";
            String snippet = "";

            // Iterating through all the locations stored
            for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++){

                // Getting the latitude of the i-th location
                lat = sharedPreferences.getString("lat"+i,"0");

                // Getting the longitude of the i-th location
                lng = sharedPreferences.getString("lng"+i,"0");

                String textstored = sharedPreferences.getString("title"+i,"0");

                String snippetstored = sharedPreferences.getString("snippet"+i,"0");

                // Drawing marker on the map
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng)))
                        .title(textstored)
                        .snippet(snippetstored)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

            }
    }
```

and

```
      googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng point) {
            AlertDialogWrapper.Builder builder = new AlertDialogWrapper.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Titel:");

            // Set up the input
            final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setView(input);

            // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    AlertDialogWrapper.Builder builderinfo = new AlertDialogWrapper.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builderinfo.setTitle("Info:");

                    // Set up the input
                    final EditText inputinfo = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                    builderinfo.setView(inputinfo);

                    // Set up the buttons
                    builderinfo.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            locationCount++;

                            // Drawing marker on the map
                            String text = input.getText().toString();
                            String textinfo = inputinfo.getText().toString();
                            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(point)
                                    .title(text)
                                    .snippet(textinfo)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

                            /** Opening the editor object to write data to sharedPreferences */
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                            // Storing the latitude for the i-th location
                            editor.putString("lat"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.latitude));

                            // Storing the longitude for the i-th location
                            editor.putString("lng"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(point.longitude));

                            editor.putString("title"+(locationCount-1), text);
                            editor.putString("snippet"+(locationCount-1),textinfo);

                            // Storing the count of locations or marker count
                            editor.putInt("locationCount", locationCount);


                            /** Saving the values stored in the shared preferences */
                            editor.commit();

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "En Markör lades till framgångsrikt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    });
```

Comment: try `googlemaps.clear();` to remove markers.

Comment: Yeah but I just want to remove 1 marker that I press from the array then save it

Comment: then remove that from array and refresh map.

Comment: Thats the problem, Im really bad with arrays and dont know how to do it :x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same class that you implement `onMapLongClick` implement [OnMarkerClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener)

As such:

```
public class MyMapView implements OnMarkerClickListener { 

  ...
  @Override
  public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // your code here
    return true; 
  }
...
}
```

Then in the `onMarkerClick(Marker marker)` you can remove the marker.

you remove the saved marker from the shared preferences using

```
editor.remove(String key);
editor.commit();
```

and from the map using:

```
marker.remove()
```

As far as the alert, I would suggest you take a look at the development guide on [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: Like this?

`googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {


                                                   }
                                               });`

I get errors on void when I do that

Comment: Sorry,I dont get it. I should make a new class? For right now I use the default class for everything, MainActivity, and I have not "implements" anything there. It looks like such 
`public class MainActivity extends Activity`
I only use that class and voids

Comment: and no, how is it tacky? Someone helped me with my code that I implemented and rewrote to suite my needs and he got a accepted answer?

Comment: So then you can just add the "implements OnMarkerClickListener" after your extends Activity and then add the override onMarkerClick() in your MainActivity class.   And I apologize,  I answered a question of yours last night, suggesting you use shared preferences to save and reload your markers, and when I saw you implemented it I assumed it was based on my answer, I guess someone else must have answered a similar question you posted on another site or something.  Again I apoloigize, if that were the case.

Comment: Thanks but how do I retrieve the string from the marker I pressed? Like how do I get the titel, info and everything from the marker I pressed? Since there is no way in advance to know whhich I press I must retreive it,right?

Yeah sorry, I got the answer from another post I read that made a little more sense for my beginner-brain, but I guess your answer was tehnically the same thing so I'll mark it correct :)

Comment: marker.getTitle()  ... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/model/Marker

Comment: when you click the marker,  that marker is passed in the onMarkerClick(Marker marker) ... now you can use any of the methods of the marker class to retrieve whatever info you need.  I think you are looking for getTitle() and getSnippet(),  but there are a bunch of methods you can call, check out the doc on the Marker class for more info.

Comment: No errors whatsoever but my code looks like this
`@Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        String nameofmarker = marker.getTitle();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove(nameofmarker);
        marker.remove();
        editor.commit();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Markör borttagen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }`
and nothing happens when I press the marker? The toast doesnt get displayed so idk what could be wrong

Comment: and you added the implements OnMarkerClickListener to your main activity class definition?

Comment: yes `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {`

Comment: Ultimately the solution to your original question involves implementing OnMarkerClickListenter().  The most basic way to do this is to declare that your class (in your case your MainActivity) implements the interface and then you need to provide the methods to actually implement that particular interface,  which is what I described above.  If you are comfortable using Toasts to debug (I use printf's and Log.d()), thats fine, but the bottom line here is that I __think__ what you are saying is that you can't get the callback to work, which is much more basic than the question you asked.

Comment: I am not trying to give you a hard time here, but stackoverflow is really intended to ask and answer specific questions that users have after doing some research or trying some solutions .  Your original question was not a bad question, but now you are really expanding it into why you can not implement a particular callback,  which is way beyond the scope of what you originally asked.